# How to align list items in centre of bootstrap grid but with list items aligning to the left?

Tags: html, css

**Please note that to simplify the code I removed some list items but they all have class="footerstyle"**

This is what the list currently looks like:

[image]

This is what I want it to look like however they have to be in the centre of a bootstrap grid:

[image]

This is my code:

```css
    .footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
    }

    footer {
        position: relative;
    }

    .list-unstyled {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .footerstyle {
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .footerstyle:hover {
        border-radius: 25px;
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom:solid 1px transparent;
    }

    .dropright {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .col-md {
        height: 200px;
        display: flex;
    }
```

```html
<div class='footer'>
  <footer class="page-footer font-small pt-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <div class="col-sm">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm">
                        <li class="footerstyle">
                            <a>Homepage</a>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm">
                        <div class="dropdown footerstyle">
                            <a class="footer-dropdown dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Team
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" >Team members</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" >Our Story</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" >Join the team</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm socialmedia">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="linkedin.png">
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <img src="twitter.png">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm cookies">
                A
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">
            <a> B </a>
        </div>
  </footer>
</div
```

The other items in the footer are in the right place and don't have this problem as they aren't list items. How can I make it so that the list items align to the left whist still being on the centre of the bootstrap grid?

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using ?

Comment: Your HTML is not valid, `div` is not allowed inside `ul`. Since HTML5 you can use `div` inside `li`, but not `ul`

Comment: And i'm bit confused, Once again clarify me your question, Are you trying to set all the content are left which is cover inside `list-unstyled` div ?

Comment: Can you share UI here or external URL of JSBin or JSFiddle?

Answer (score -1):

To align text left just add this code to your css:

`.page-footer a {
    text-align:left;
  }`